# jQuery delegateing inside div > divs > a also :(

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation, delegation

html:

```
<div id="a">
  <a id="a0" href="#"></a>

  <div id="b"><a id="b0" href="#"></a><div>
<div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#a').delegate('a', 'click', function(){ //do stuff });
```

delegates #b0 as well. Is there any clever selector way of ways to ignore #b ?

NB /// links inside divs are added and detached dynamically ///

ty

Comment: Worth noting that while `.delegate()` is supported in jQuery 1.7+, the new `.on()` function replaces it and is consequently more future-proof (1.7 also improves performance of event binding in general). The syntax is nearly identical, except the event ('click') and the selector ('a' in sample or Luke's suggested variants) are reversed.

Comment: **.on() vs .delegate()** :  how about perfomance speeds and browser compatibilty?

Comment: .on() is essentially .bind() and .delegate() rolled up into one, and performance gains are coincidental because of refactoring. .on() will be faster (just because it's refactored) and both should be equally cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you know it's only direct descendants try

```
$('#a').delegate('#a>a', 'click', function(){ alert('a') });
```

if you know you want to ignore children of b try

```
$('#a').delegate('a:not(#b>a)', 'click', function(){ alert('a') });
```

EDIT: [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GAW99/1/)

Comment: thank you :), never occoured to me to make selector inside delegate

Comment: no worries. FYI I would think about using classes to identify your elements, as it makes restructuring later a bit easier (and it's way more obvious what's going on)

Answer (score 0):

This is working as expected. Your `delegate()` call will set event handler for all children under `#a` that match selector `a`.

If you are trying to set handler for a specific element then do that

```
$('#a0').click(function(){ ... });
```

Also your html is pretty broken. Make sure closing tags actually closing.

Comment: The `.click()` alias sets the listener to self. Most people use `.delegate()` / `.on()` (as a delegation tool) because they don't want this.

Comment: @GregPettit That is not how I read his question, but if we assume that `aX` anchors are also added dynamically, then yes.

Answer (score -1):

The first field in the delegate method is the selector. As of now, you are selecting all the anchors. Use id instead.

Comment: he wants it to work for any 'a' he adds, except the ones that are in #b

Comment: then he can group them under a class.

Comment: totally right :) I even made a comment to that effect against the question. It might be a good idea if you ammended your answer to include your suggestion instead of your original incorrect (misled perhaps?) answer

Comment: I don't think, my answer would mislead anyone. Anyway, everyone has their opinion. I respect yours :)

Comment: no no no I meant I think you were misled in your analysis of the problem (maybe didn't read the NB) as opposed to just being totally wrong :) Basically, I don't think you answered his need - not because you don't know what you're talking about, but probable because you misread it - hence 'misled' instead of 'incorrect'

Answer (score -1):

jQuery1.7 or above

```
$('#a').on('click', '#a0', function(event) {
    alert(event.target.id);
});
```

Comment: as I commented elsewhere, he wants essentially 'live' events (so, delegated to the parent) so he can dynamically add elements later without having to bind their events.